# Start a timer which expires in millisec in Windows C

Tags: c, windows, timer

I'm developing a C program in windows. I want to start a timer which has an expiry period of millisec range. I have worked in RTOS, in those, RTOS provides API for timers creation, starting and stopping and it's handler.

So how can I avail these kind of features in windows programming environment?

Comment: [First googled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438386/how-to-implement-a-timer-in-c-on-windows)......

Comment: @ZahiroMor is a [tag:c] question for [tag:windows] platform about timers, not time

Comment: If you need a realtime OS, you need a realtime OS. Timers on Windows don't come with hard realtime guarantees. If you are fine with a granularity of 10ms, Windows timers could be a solution. However, your question doesn't contain a very detailed specification.

Comment: ^^^ a desktop OS is just that.  It does desktop things really well.

Comment: Not possible, Windows is not a RTOS.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, if you are doing this through window messaging, you can use `SetTimer` API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx

And when the timer fires, your window will receive the `WM_TIMER` message, in which you can handle the timer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ScottStensland: Those links are links to official documentation, both for `SetTimer` as well as `WM_TIMER`. Should those links ever become invalid, the answer would still contain enough information to search and find the documentation. When performing reviews outside your field of expertise you need to be extra careful. In this case you clearly went for the wrong option.

Comment: Why do I have to have a reason for someone else's vote?